# JNI crashing JVM - A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment: EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION

Tags: java, jvm, java-native-interface, fatal-error, jvm-crash

I'm getting this error during program execution which crashes the JVM. There is third party code for which we don't have access to source. It looks like it is making use of JNI to execute some native code which crashes JVM.

The program runs in a loop but doesn't always crash the JVM.
JVM crash happens occasionally. Can someone help in identifying the error? Thanks

It uses Java 8 on Windows. As per the error, The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code. Could it be the problem with JVM?

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x718b21f4, pid=3352, tid=0x00002430
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_201-b09) (build 1.8.0_201-b09)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (25.201-b09 mixed mode, sharing windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  [msvcr100.dll+0x121f4]
#
# Core dump written. Default location: C:\Scripts\BotRestorer\hs_err_pid3352.mdmp
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x17bb3800):  JavaThread "Thread-2" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=9264, stack(0x18940000,0x18a20000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0xc615c2c0

Registers:
EAX=0xc615c2c0, EBX=0x00000000, ECX=0x00000000, EDX=0x16f150cc
ESP=0x18a1f448, EBP=0x18a1f448, ESI=0x19b2ab40, EDI=0x17bb3940
EIP=0x718b21f4, EFLAGS=0x00010202

Top of Stack: (sp=0x18a1f448)
0x18a1f448:   18a1f488 70b3e30f c615c2c0 dbc999cc
0x18a1f458:   17bb3800 188329b8 188329b8 17ac0a04
0x18a1f468:   19b2ab40 00002d70 0000000d 00000000
0x18a1f478:   18a1f454 18a1f67c 70b85f96 00000001
0x18a1f488:   18a1f4bc 02b5daf1 00000000 18a1f4cc
0x18a1f498:   00000000 18a1f49c 00000000 18a1f4cc
0x18a1f4a8:   18832ee0 00000000 188329b8 00000000
0x18a1f4b8:   18a1f4d0 18a1f568 02ea7bc4 00000000 

Instructions: (pc=0x718b21f4)
0x718b21d4:   48 95 71 00 0f 84 bd 20 00 00 6a 00 ff 75 08 e8
0x718b21e4:   8a 22 00 00 59 59 5d c3 8b ff 55 8b ec 8b 45 08
0x718b21f4:   66 8b 08 83 c0 02 66 85 c9 75 f5 2b 45 08 d1 f8
0x718b2204:   48 5d c3 8b ff 55 8b ec 51 53 56 8b 75 08 f6 46 


Register to memory mapping:

EAX=0xc615c2c0 is an unknown value
EBX=0x00000000 is an unknown value
ECX=0x00000000 is an unknown value
EDX=0x16f150cc is an unknown value
ESP=0x18a1f448 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x17bb3800
EBP=0x18a1f448 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x17bb3800
ESI=0x19b2ab40 is an unknown value
EDI=0x17bb3940 is an unknown value


Stack: [0x18940000,0x18a20000],  sp=0x18a1f448,  free space=893k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [msvcr100.dll+0x121f4]
C  [awt.dll+0x6e30f]
j  sun.print.Win32PrintServiceLookup.getAllPrinterNames()[Ljava/lang/String;+0
J 3532 C1 sun.print.Win32PrintServiceLookup.refreshServices()V (282 bytes) @ 0x02ea7bc4 [0x02ea7ae0+0xe4]
j  sun.print.Win32PrintServiceLookup.access$200(Lsun/print/Win32PrintServiceLookup;)V+1
j  sun.print.Win32PrintServiceLookup$PrinterChangeListener.run()V+29
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
V  [jvm.dll+0x15c215]
V  [jvm.dll+0x22512e]
V  [jvm.dll+0x15c2ae]
V  [jvm.dll+0x15c436]
V  [jvm.dll+0x15c4a7]
V  [jvm.dll+0x1001df]
V  [jvm.dll+0x17f590]
V  [jvm.dll+0x17fe0a]
V  [jvm.dll+0x1c6a76]
C  [msvcr100.dll+0x5c556]
C  [msvcr100.dll+0x5c600]
C  [KERNEL32.DLL+0x162c4]
C  [ntdll.dll+0x61f69]
C  [ntdll.dll+0x61f34]
C  0x00000000

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  sun.print.Win32PrintServiceLookup.getAllPrinterNames()[Ljava/lang/String;+0
J 3532 C1 sun.print.Win32PrintServiceLookup.refreshServices()V (282 bytes) @ 0x02ea7bc4 [0x02ea7ae0+0xe4]
j  sun.print.Win32PrintServiceLookup.access$200(Lsun/print/Win32PrintServiceLookup;)V+1
j  sun.print.Win32PrintServiceLookup$PrinterChangeListener.run()V+29
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x1801b000 JavaThread "RMI TCP Connection(idle)" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6624, stack(0x1b970000,0x1ba50000)]
  0x1801ac00 JavaThread "RMI TCP Connection(120)-10.15.125.221" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=7592, stack(0x1b790000,0x1b870000)]
  0x1801a400 JavaThread "RMI TCP Connection(118)-10.15.125.221" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=6828, stack(0x17410000,0x174f0000)]
  0x18016c00 JavaThread "Background Batch Spiller 2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4668, stack(0x1b070000,0x1b150000)]
  0x17d68000 JavaThread "Background Batch Spiller 1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2200, stack(0x1af90000,0x1b070000)]
  0x17d69400 JavaThread "Background Batch Spiller 0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5112, stack(0x1ac70000,0x1ad50000)]
  0x17d68800 JavaThread "oracle.jdbc.driver.BlockSource.ThreadedCachingBlockSource.BlockReleaser" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8496, stack(0x18ca0000,0x18d80000)]
  0x17a5a800 JavaThread "AWT-Windows" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=7612, stack(0x18dc0000,0x18ea0000)]
  0x17c59400 JavaThread "Java2D Disposer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2916, stack(0x18ac0000,0x18ba0000)]
=>0x17bb3800 JavaThread "Thread-2" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=9264, stack(0x18940000,0x18a20000)]
  0x16e4ac00 JavaThread "JRC Timeout Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=372, stack(0x176c0000,0x177a0000)]
  0x164b8000 JavaThread "Thread Pool Worker #0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=11628, stack(0x174f0000,0x175d0000)]
  0x02a12c00 JavaThread "DestroyJavaVM" [_thread_blocked, id=1284, stack(0x01270000,0x012c0000)]
  0x16d4f400 JavaThread "RMI Scheduler(0)" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2808, stack(0x17330000,0x17410000)]
  0x16cecc00 JavaThread "GC Daemon" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6184, stack(0x17210000,0x172f0000)]
  0x16ceb400 JavaThread "RMI Reaper" [_thread_blocked, id=10428, stack(0x170f0000,0x171d0000)]
  0x16cd7c00 JavaThread "RMI TCP Accept-0" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=4784, stack(0x17010000,0x170f0000)]
  0x02ad9000 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2168, stack(0x163c0000,0x164a0000)]
  0x02ab0400 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=12028, stack(0x15cb0000,0x15d00000)]
  0x02aae000 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6748, stack(0x15b90000,0x15c70000)]
  0x02a96000 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=11940, stack(0x15980000,0x15a60000)]
  0x02a3bc00 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7228, stack(0x15860000,0x15940000)]

Other Threads:
  0x02a39800 VMThread [stack: 0x15190000,0x151e0000] [id=5076]
  0x02ae3800 WatcherThread [stack: 0x15d80000,0x15dd0000] [id=1968]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap:
 def new generation   total 78656K, used 33613K [0x04c00000, 0x0a150000, 0x0a150000)
  eden space 69952K,  48% used [0x04c00000, 0x06cd37f0, 0x09050000)
  from space 8704K,   0% used [0x098d0000, 0x098d0000, 0x0a150000)
  to   space 8704K,   0% used [0x09050000, 0x09050000, 0x098d0000)
 tenured generation   total 174784K, used 20192K [0x0a150000, 0x14c00000, 0x14c00000)
   the space 174784K,  11% used [0x0a150000, 0x0b508018, 0x0b508200, 0x14c00000)
 Metaspace       used 25422K, capacity 25614K, committed 25728K, reserved 25984K

Card table byte_map: [0x14c00000,0x14c90000] byte_map_base: 0x14bda000

Polling page: 0x01090000

CodeCache: size=32768Kb used=4141Kb max_used=4760Kb free=28626Kb
 bounds [0x02b50000, 0x02ff8000, 0x04b50000]
 total_blobs=2202 nmethods=1885 adapters=247
 compilation: enabled

Compilation events (10 events):
Event: 9085.713 Thread 0x02ab0400 4075   !         com.crystaldecisions.reports.formulas.o::a (169 bytes)
Event: 9085.715 Thread 0x02ab0400 nmethod 4075 0x02f88dc8 code [0x02f88f90, 0x02f89564]
Event: 9085.778 Thread 0x02ab0400 4076             com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.data.Fields::getField (9 bytes)
Event: 9085.778 Thread 0x02ab0400 nmethod 4076 0x02f9d148 code [0x02f9d250, 0x02f9d32c]
Event: 9085.792 Thread 0x02ab0400 4077             java.lang.Long::stringSize (38 bytes)
Event: 9085.792 Thread 0x02ab0400 nmethod 4077 0x02f88b88 code [0x02f88c80, 0x02f88d70]
Event: 9088.237 Thread 0x02ab0400 4078             com.crystaldecisions.reports.queryengine.Property::vW (15 bytes)
Event: 9088.237 Thread 0x02ab0400 nmethod 4078 0x02f88988 code [0x02f88a80, 0x02f88b20]
Event: 9088.527 Thread 0x02ab0400 4079             oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetMetaData::getDescription (8 bytes)
Event: 9088.527 Thread 0x02ab0400 nmethod 4079 0x02f88748 code [0x02f88850, 0x02f888ec]

GC Heap History (10 events):
Event: 6338.685 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=7 (full 4):
 def new generation   total 78656K, used 78621K [0x04c00000, 0x0a150000, 0x0a150000)
  eden space 69952K, 100% used [0x04c00000, 0x09050000, 0x09050000)
  from space 8704K,  99% used [0x098d0000, 0x0a1475f0, 0x0a150000)
  to   space 8704K,   0% used [0x09050000, 0x09050000, 0x098d0000)
 tenured generation   total 174784K, used 14620K [0x0a150000, 0x14c00000, 0x14c00000)
   the space 174784K,   8% used [0x0a150000, 0x0af97038, 0x0af97200, 0x14c00000)
 Metaspace       used 24975K, capacity 25173K, committed 25216K, reserved 25984K
Event: 6338.720 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=8 (full 4):
 def new generation   total 78656K, used 1059K [0x04c00000, 0x0a150000, 0x0a150000)
  eden space 69952K,   0% used [0x04c00000, 0x04c00000, 0x09050000)
  from space 8704K,  12% used [0x09050000, 0x09158c38, 0x098d0000)
  to   space 8704K,   0% used [0x098d0000, 0x098d0000, 0x0a150000)
 tenured generation   total 174784K, used 19678K [0x0a150000, 0x14c00000, 0x14c00000)
   the space 174784K,  11% used [0x0a150000, 0x0b487a00, 0x0b487a00, 0x14c00000)
 Metaspace       used 24975K, capacity 25173K, committed 25216K, reserved 25984K
}
Event: 6962.583 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=8 (full 4):
 def new generation   total 78656K, used 70608K [0x04c00000, 0x0a150000, 0x0a150000)
  eden space 69952K,  99% used [0x04c00000, 0x08feb580, 0x09050000)
  from space 8704K,  12% used [0x09050000, 0x09158c38, 0x098d0000)
  to   space 8704K,   0% used [0x098d0000, 0x098d0000, 0x0a150000)
 tenured generation   total 174784K, used 19678K [0x0a150000, 0x14c00000, 0x14c00000)
   the space 174784K,  11% used [0x0a150000, 0x0b487a00, 0x0b487a00, 0x14c00000)
 Metaspace       used 25390K, capacity 25589K, committed 25728K, reserved 25984K
Event: 6962.603 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=9 (full 4):
 def new generation   total 78656K, used 1516K [0x04c00000, 0x0a150000, 0x0a150000)
  eden space 69952K,   0% used [0x04c00000, 0x04c00000, 0x09050000)
  from space 8704K,  17% used [0x098d0000, 0x09a4b328, 0x0a150000)
  to   space 8704K,   0% used [0x09050000, 0x09050000, 0x098d0000)
 tenured generation   total 174784K, used 19678K [0x0a150000, 0x14c00000, 0x14c00000)
   the space 174784K,  11% used [0x0a150000, 0x0b487a00, 0x0b487a00, 0x14c00000)
 Metaspace       used 25390K, capacity 25589K, committed 25728K, reserved 25984K
}
Event: 7297.367 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=9 (full 4):
 def new generation   total 78656K, used 71468K [0x04c00000, 0x0a150000, 0x0a150000)
  eden space 69952K, 100% used [0x04c00000, 0x09050000, 0x09050000)
  from space 8704K,  17% used [0x098d0000, 0x09a4b328, 0x0a150000)
  to   space 8704K,   0% used [0x09050000, 0x09050000, 0x098d0000)
 tenured generation   total 174784K, used 19678K [0x0a150000, 0x14c00000, 0x14c00000)
   the space 174784K,  11% used [0x0a150000, 0x0b487a00, 0x0b487a00, 0x14c00000)
 Metaspace       used 25390K, capacity 25589K, committed 25728K, reserved 25984K
Event: 7297.382 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=10 (full 4):
 def new generation   total 78656K, used 1154K [0x04c00000, 0x0a150000, 0x0a150000)
  eden space 69952K,   0% used [0x04c00000, 0x04c00000, 0x09050000)
  from space 8704K,  13% used [0x09050000, 0x09170890, 0x098d0000)
  to   space 8704K,   0% used [0x098d0000, 0x098d0000, 0x0a150000)
 tenured generation   total 174784K, used 19678K [0x0a150000, 0x14c00000, 0x14c00000)
   the space 174784K,  11% used [0x0a150000, 0x0b487a00, 0x0b487a00, 0x14c00000)
 Metaspace       used 25390K, capacity 25589K, committed 25728K, reserved 25984K
}
Event: 7812.078 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=10 (full 4):
 def new generation   total 78656K, used 71106K [0x04c00000, 0x0a150000, 0x0a150000)
  eden space 69952K, 100% used [0x04c00000, 0x09050000, 0x09050000)
  from space 8704K,  13% used [0x09050000, 0x09170890, 0x098d0000)
  to   space 8704K,   0% used [0x098d0000, 0x098d0000, 0x0a150000)
 tenured generation   total 174784K, used 19678K [0x0a150000, 0x14c00000, 0x14c00000)
   the space 174784K,  11% used [0x0a150000, 0x0b487a00, 0x0b487a00, 0x14c00000)
 Metaspace       used 25390K, capacity 25589K, committed 25728K, reserved 25984K
Event: 7812.093 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=11 (full 4):
 def new generation   total 78656K, used 998K [0x04c00000, 0x0a150000, 0x0a150000)
  eden space 69952K,   0% used [0x04c00000, 0x04c00000, 0x09050000)
  from space 8704K,  11% used [0x098d0000, 0x099c99f0, 0x0a150000)
  to   space 8704K,   0% used [0x09050000, 0x09050000, 0x098d0000)
 tenured generation   total 174784K, used 19678K [0x0a150000, 0x14c00000, 0x14c00000)
   the space 174784K,  11% used [0x0a150000, 0x0b487a00, 0x0b487a00, 0x14c00000)
 Metaspace       used 25390K, capacity 25589K, committed 25728K, reserved 25984K
}
Event: 8581.459 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=11 (full 4):
 def new generation   total 78656K, used 63387K [0x04c00000, 0x0a150000, 0x0a150000)
  eden space 69952K,  89% used [0x04c00000, 0x088ed4f8, 0x09050000)
  from space 8704K,  11% used [0x098d0000, 0x099c99f0, 0x0a150000)
  to   space 8704K,   0% used [0x09050000, 0x09050000, 0x098d0000)
 tenured generation   total 174784K, used 19678K [0x0a150000, 0x14c00000, 0x14c00000)
   the space 174784K,  11% used [0x0a150000, 0x0b487a00, 0x0b487a00, 0x14c00000)
 Metaspace       used 25390K, capacity 25589K, committed 25728K, reserved 25984K
Event: 8581.601 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=12 (full 5):
 def new generation   total 78656K, used 0K [0x04c00000, 0x0a150000, 0x0a150000)
  eden space 69952K,   0% used [0x04c00000, 0x04c00000, 0x09050000)
  from space 8704K,   0% used [0x098d0000, 0x098d0000, 0x0a150000)
  to   space 8704K,   0% used [0x09050000, 0x09050000, 0x098d0000)
 tenured generation   total 174784K, used 20192K [0x0a150000, 0x14c00000, 0x14c00000)
   the space 174784K,  11% used [0x0a150000, 0x0b508018, 0x0b508200, 0x14c00000)
 Metaspace       used 25376K, capacity 25572K, committed 25728K, reserved 25984K
}

Deoptimization events (0 events):
No events

Classes redefined (0 events):
No events

Internal exceptions (10 events):
Event: 9063.770 Thread 0x18019800 Exception <a 'java/lang/ClassCastException'> (0x05e52be8) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-i586-cygwin\jdk8u201\12322\hotspot\src\share\vm\runtime\sharedRuntime.cpp, line 605]
Event: 9063.772 Thread 0x18019800 Exception <a 'java/lang/ClassCastException'> (0x05e57450) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-i586-cygwin\jdk8u201\12322\hotspot\src\share\vm\runtime\sharedRuntime.cpp, line 605]
Event: 9071.621 Thread 0x164b8000 Exception <a 'java/lang/ClassNotFoundException': sun/net/www/protocol/c/Handler> (0x05fcfdf0) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-i586-cygwin\jdk8u201\12322\hotspot\src\share\vm\classfile\systemDictionary.cpp, line 210]
Event: 9074.913 Thread 0x18018400 Exception <a 'java/lang/ClassCastException'> (0x0659a118) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-i586-cygwin\jdk8u201\12322\hotspot\src\share\vm\runtime\sharedRuntime.cpp, line 605]
Event: 9074.915 Thread 0x18018400 Exception <a 'java/lang/ClassCastException'> (0x0659e530) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-i586-cygwin\jdk8u201\12322\hotspot\src\share\vm\runtime\sharedRuntime.cpp, line 605]
Event: 9074.918 Thread 0x18018400 Exception <a 'java/lang/ClassCastException'> (0x065a7e70) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-i586-cygwin\jdk8u201\12322\hotspot\src\share\vm\runtime\sharedRuntime.cpp, line 605]
Event: 9074.920 Thread 0x18018400 Exception <a 'java/lang/ClassCastException'> (0x065aca30) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-i586-cygwin\jdk8u201\12322\hotspot\src\share\vm\runtime\sharedRuntime.cpp, line 605]
Event: 9074.922 Thread 0x18018400 Exception <a 'java/lang/ClassCastException'> (0x065b3ac0) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-i586-cygwin\jdk8u201\12322\hotspot\src\share\vm\runtime\sharedRuntime.cpp, line 605]
Event: 9074.923 Thread 0x18018400 Exception <a 'java/lang/ClassCastException'> (0x065b7ea0) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-i586-cygwin\jdk8u201\12322\hotspot\src\share\vm\runtime\sharedRuntime.cpp, line 605]
Event: 9085.545 Thread 0x164b8000 Exception <a 'java/lang/ClassNotFoundException': sun/net/www/protocol/c/Handler> (0x067c5460) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-i586-cygwin\jdk8u201\12322\hotspot\src\share\vm\classfile\systemDictionary.cpp, line 210]

Events (10 events):
Event: 9085.560 Thread 0x02ab0400 flushing nmethod 0x02faa308
Event: 9085.560 Thread 0x02ab0400 flushing nmethod 0x02faa788
Event: 9085.560 loading class org/apache/crimson/parser/XMLReaderImpl
Event: 9085.560 loading class org/apache/crimson/parser/XMLReaderImpl done
Event: 9085.561 loading class gnu/xml/aelfred2/XmlReader
Event: 9085.561 loading class gnu/xml/aelfred2/XmlReader done
Event: 9085.804 loading class weblogic/jndi/WLInitialContextFactory
Event: 9085.804 loading class weblogic/jndi/WLInitialContextFactory done
Event: 9088.558 Executing VM operation: RevokeBias
Event: 9088.559 Executing VM operation: RevokeBias done


Dynamic libraries:
0x00e30000 - 0x00e63000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\bin\java.exe
0x770c0000 - 0x77243000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
0x74090000 - 0x74170000     C:\Windows\System32\KERNEL32.DLL
0x74750000 - 0x748f2000     C:\Windows\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
0x719f0000 - 0x71a82000     C:\Windows\system32\apphelp.dll
0x74010000 - 0x74087000     C:\Windows\System32\ADVAPI32.dll
0x73c40000 - 0x73cfe000     C:\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll
0x74be0000 - 0x74c21000     C:\Windows\System32\sechost.dll
0x74680000 - 0x74741000     C:\Windows\System32\RPCRT4.dll
0x73ba0000 - 0x73bbf000     C:\Windows\System32\SspiCli.dll
0x73b90000 - 0x73b9a000     C:\Windows\System32\CRYPTBASE.dll
0x74620000 - 0x7467a000     C:\Windows\System32\bcryptPrimitives.dll
0x74360000 - 0x744bf000     C:\Windows\System32\USER32.dll
0x74ae0000 - 0x74af5000     C:\Windows\System32\win32u.dll
0x76f00000 - 0x76f2b000     C:\Windows\System32\GDI32.dll
0x744c0000 - 0x7461a000     C:\Windows\System32\gdi32full.dll
0x726a0000 - 0x728aa000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.14393.2938_none_c58b03c797c07d8c\COMCTL32.dll
0x73e00000 - 0x74010000     C:\Windows\System32\combase.dll
0x76410000 - 0x764f0000     C:\Windows\System32\ucrtbase.dll
0x74ba0000 - 0x74bc5000     C:\Windows\System32\IMM32.DLL
0x718a0000 - 0x7195f000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\bin\msvcr100.dll
0x714c0000 - 0x71895000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\bin\client\jvm.dll
0x76ef0000 - 0x76ef6000     C:\Windows\System32\PSAPI.DLL
0x73000000 - 0x73008000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WSOCK32.dll
0x74a70000 - 0x74ad3000     C:\Windows\System32\WS2_32.dll
0x71490000 - 0x714b4000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WINMM.dll
0x73700000 - 0x73708000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\VERSION.dll
0x71460000 - 0x71483000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WINMMBASE.dll
0x77020000 - 0x77056000     C:\Windows\System32\cfgmgr32.dll
0x713e0000 - 0x713ec000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\bin\verify.dll
0x713b0000 - 0x713d1000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\bin\java.dll
0x71390000 - 0x713a4000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\bin\zip.dll
0x74eb0000 - 0x76284000     C:\Windows\System32\SHELL32.dll
0x764f0000 - 0x76a5e000     C:\Windows\System32\windows.storage.dll
0x77070000 - 0x770b5000     C:\Windows\System32\powrprof.dll
0x74da0000 - 0x74de6000     C:\Windows\System32\shlwapi.dll
0x74ea0000 - 0x74ead000     C:\Windows\System32\kernel.appcore.dll
0x74900000 - 0x74988000     C:\Windows\System32\shcore.dll
0x73df0000 - 0x73dff000     C:\Windows\System32\profapi.dll
0x730e0000 - 0x730f3000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\CRYPTSP.dll
0x730b0000 - 0x730df000     C:\Windows\system32\rsaenh.dll
0x73640000 - 0x7365b000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\bcrypt.dll
0x72df0000 - 0x72e0a000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\USERENV.dll
0x72200000 - 0x72215000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\bin\net.dll
0x71ec0000 - 0x72055000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\urlmon.dll
0x71c80000 - 0x71eb6000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\iertutil.dll
0x72650000 - 0x7269e000     C:\Windows\system32\mswsock.dll
0x73130000 - 0x7315f000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\IPHLPAPI.DLL
0x74bd0000 - 0x74bd7000     C:\Windows\System32\NSI.dll
0x721e0000 - 0x721f3000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\dhcpcsvc6.DLL
0x721c0000 - 0x721d4000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\dhcpcsvc.DLL
0x721b0000 - 0x721bf000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\bin\nio.dll
0x720d0000 - 0x720da000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\bin\management.dll
0x72130000 - 0x72142000     C:\Windows\system32\napinsp.dll
0x73160000 - 0x731dd000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\DNSAPI.dll
0x72120000 - 0x7212c000     C:\Windows\System32\winrnr.dll
0x72100000 - 0x72114000     C:\Windows\system32\NLAapi.dll
0x71b50000 - 0x71b58000     C:\Windows\System32\rasadhlp.dll
0x71960000 - 0x719a9000     C:\Windows\System32\fwpuclnt.dll
0x04bd0000 - 0x04bf4000     C:\Users\svcjgb_crpt\AppData\Local\Temp\JRCJNI\JRCJNI_3426275850577281976.dll
0x74b00000 - 0x74b96000     C:\Windows\System32\OLEAUT32.dll
0x71ba0000 - 0x71c0a000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WINSPOOL.DRV
0x73bc0000 - 0x73c3b000     C:\Windows\System32\msvcp_win.dll
0x70e50000 - 0x70ea4000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\OLEACC.dll
0x70ad0000 - 0x70c17000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\bin\awt.dll
0x71c10000 - 0x71c2f000     C:\Windows\system32\DWMAPI.DLL
0x72220000 - 0x72295000     C:\Windows\system32\uxtheme.dll
0x72060000 - 0x72099000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\bin\fontmanager.dll
0x74220000 - 0x74355000     C:\Windows\System32\MSCTF.dll
0x73d00000 - 0x73dec000     C:\Windows\System32\ole32.dll
0x71b80000 - 0x71b9c000     C:\app\client\svcjgb_crpt\product\12.1.0\client_1\BIN\ocijdbc12.dll
0x709d0000 - 0x70ace000     C:\app\client\svcjgb_crpt\product\12.1.0\client_1\bin\OCI.dll
0x70510000 - 0x709c6000     C:\app\client\svcjgb_crpt\product\12.1.0\client_1\bin\OraClient12.Dll
0x702c0000 - 0x7042e000     C:\app\client\svcjgb_crpt\product\12.1.0\client_1\bin\oracore12.dll
0x71b60000 - 0x71b7b000     C:\app\client\svcjgb_crpt\product\12.1.0\client_1\bin\oraunls12.dll
0x70430000 - 0x70507000     C:\app\client\svcjgb_crpt\product\12.1.0\client_1\bin\oranls12.dll
0x6fc70000 - 0x70273000     C:\app\client\svcjgb_crpt\product\12.1.0\client_1\bin\oracommon12.dll
0x6d840000 - 0x6e8ba000     C:\app\client\svcjgb_crpt\product\12.1.0\client_1\bin\orageneric12.dll
0x6f710000 - 0x6fc6e000     C:\app\client\svcjgb_crpt\product\12.1.0\client_1\bin\oraxml12.dll
0x70280000 - 0x702b1000     C:\app\client\svcjgb_crpt\product\12.1.0\client_1\bin\oraons.dll
0x6f330000 - 0x6f70b000     C:\app\client\svcjgb_crpt\product\12.1.0\client_1\bin\oran12.dll
0x6ede0000 - 0x6f24a000     C:\app\client\svcjgb_crpt\product\12.1.0\client_1\bin\oraldapclnt12.dll
0x6e9c0000 - 0x6edd9000     C:\app\client\svcjgb_crpt\product\12.1.0\client_1\bin\orannzsbb12.dll
0x6f2a0000 - 0x6f321000     C:\app\client\svcjgb_crpt\product\12.1.0\client_1\bin\oranl12.dll
0x6f250000 - 0x6f29f000     C:\app\client\svcjgb_crpt\product\12.1.0\client_1\bin\oranro12.dll
0x76290000 - 0x7640d000     C:\Windows\System32\CRYPT32.dll
0x77060000 - 0x7706e000     C:\Windows\System32\MSASN1.dll
0x6d110000 - 0x6d673000     C:\app\client\svcjgb_crpt\product\12.1.0\client_1\bin\orapls12.dll
0x6e900000 - 0x6e9b7000     C:\app\client\svcjgb_crpt\product\12.1.0\client_1\bin\orasql12.dll
0x71c30000 - 0x71c36000     C:\app\client\svcjgb_crpt\product\12.1.0\client_1\bin\orauts.dll
0x6e8c0000 - 0x6e8f4000     C:\app\client\svcjgb_crpt\product\12.1.0\client_1\bin\orasnls12.dll
0x6d6e0000 - 0x6d7cb000     C:\app\client\svcjgb_crpt\product\12.1.0\client_1\bin\oraasmclnt12.dll
0x72c60000 - 0x72c73000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\NETAPI32.dll
0x6d0a0000 - 0x6d0d7000     C:\app\client\svcjgb_crpt\product\12.1.0\client_1\bin\orawsec12.dll
0x6bb80000 - 0x6c331000     C:\app\client\svcjgb_crpt\product\12.1.0\client_1\bin\orahasgen12.dll
0x6cff0000 - 0x6d001000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\wsnmp32.dll
0x6c600000 - 0x6c6ec000     C:\app\client\svcjgb_crpt\product\12.1.0\client_1\bin\oraocr12.dll
0x6cb70000 - 0x6cfeb000     C:\app\client\svcjgb_crpt\product\12.1.0\client_1\bin\orazt12.dll
0x6c4b0000 - 0x6c5f5000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\dbghelp.dll
0x6d7d0000 - 0x6d839000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\MSVCP100.dll
0x713f0000 - 0x7140d000     C:\app\client\svcjgb_crpt\product\12.1.0\client_1\bin\orancrypt12.dll
0x6d690000 - 0x6d6d4000     C:\app\client\svcjgb_crpt\product\12.1.0\client_1\bin\oranldap12.dll
0x70e40000 - 0x70e46000     C:\app\client\svcjgb_crpt\product\12.1.0\client_1\bin\orancds12.dll
0x719e0000 - 0x719e9000     C:\app\client\svcjgb_crpt\product\12.1.0\client_1\bin\oranhost12.dll
0x6d680000 - 0x6d68d000     C:\app\client\svcjgb_crpt\product\12.1.0\client_1\bin\orantns12.dll
0x6c6f0000 - 0x6cb6c000     C:\app\client\svcjgb_crpt\product\12.1.0\client_1\bin\oraztkg12.dll
0x6d010000 - 0x6d09d000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\CRYPTUI.dll
0x6d0e0000 - 0x6d10f000     C:\app\client\svcjgb_crpt\product\12.1.0\client_1\bin\orantcp12.dll
0x6c420000 - 0x6c42a000     C:\app\client\svcjgb_crpt\product\12.1.0\client_1\bin\oraslax12.dll
0x6c410000 - 0x6c416000     C:\app\client\svcjgb_crpt\product\12.1.0\client_1\bin\oravsn12.dll
0x6b780000 - 0x6bb73000     C:\app\client\svcjgb_crpt\product\12.1.0\client_1\bin\oraplp12.dll
0x6c430000 - 0x6c4a1000     C:\app\client\svcjgb_crpt\product\12.1.0\client_1\bin\oracell12.dll
0x72bc0000 - 0x72bca000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\Secur32.dll
0x6b760000 - 0x6b773000     C:\app\client\svcjgb_crpt\product\12.1.0\client_1\bin\oraocrutl12.dll
0x6b720000 - 0x6b753000     C:\app\client\svcjgb_crpt\product\12.1.0\client_1\bin\oraclsce12.dll
0x6c340000 - 0x6c3ed000     C:\app\client\svcjgb_crpt\product\12.1.0\client_1\bin\oraocrb12.dll
0x72b30000 - 0x72b3b000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\NETUTILS.DLL
0x6c3f0000 - 0x6c405000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\SAMCLI.DLL
0x72160000 - 0x7217c000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\SRVCLI.DLL
0x6b6e0000 - 0x6b70f000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\LOGONCLI.DLL
0x6b710000 - 0x6b720000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WKSCLI.DLL
0x6b6c0000 - 0x6b6dd000     C:\app\client\svcjgb_crpt\product\12.1.0\client_1\bin\OraPlc12.Dll
0x72150000 - 0x7215f000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\cscapi.dll
0x6b470000 - 0x6b4a2000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\bin\t2k.dll
0x6b5e0000 - 0x6b6c0000     C:\Windows\system32\opengl32.dll
0x6b5b0000 - 0x6b5d5000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\GLU32.dll
0x6b4c0000 - 0x6b5ad000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\DDRAW.dll
0x6b4b0000 - 0x6b4b7000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\DCIMAN32.dll
```

Comment: If you can skip the code (e.g. it doesn't do something essential) you can always try to handle the signal: http://jnicookbook.owsiak.org/recipe-No-015/

Answer (score 7):

This is a JDK bug - [JDK-8182683](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8182683). Unfortunately, it is not confirmed, and there is no known fix.

The crash happend when Windows Printer Change notification fired. I guess the problem is related to the following code in [getPrinterNames](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/35818757a9c6/src/windows/native/sun/windows/WPrinterJob.cpp#l136) function:

```
    ::EnumPrinters(flags,
                   NULL, 4, NULL, 0, &cbNeeded, &cReturned);
    pPrinterEnum = new BYTE[cbNeeded];
    ::EnumPrinters(flags,
                   NULL, 4, pPrinterEnum, cbNeeded, &cbNeeded,
                   &cReturned);
```

Here `EnumPrinters` is called twice, but the result is not checked. If the function fails for some reason, the variables may remain inconsistent.

Apparently, I've found a funny workaround. It seems that `PrinterChangeListener` thread is [not started](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/35818757a9c6/src/windows/classes/sun/print/PrintServiceLookupProvider.java#l123) on Windows 98. So, if you add `-Dos.name="Windows 98"` JVM option, Java will not listen to Printer Change notifications, and the problematic function will not be called.

Comment: `GetAdaptersInfo` has the same API and also occasionally fails. I believe the modern recommendation is to allocate a large enough buffer up front instead of trusting the `cbNeeded` size. I don't suppose OP has the luxury of patching their JVM? :)

Comment: Thanks for pointing to the code that is causing the crash. We faced the same problem and with this pointer we managed to reproduce the issue. We opened a case with Oracle and they fixed it :) https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8262829